# Why do I get different apperances when I use different addresses using Python Flask?

Tags: python, web, flask

I wrote a Web based app using Python Flask. 
When I run it using the localhost address, I get the results shown in the bottom of the attached image. 
When I change the address to my PC IP address (and still running it from the same PC using the same browser), I get bigger fonts and skewed tables (the bigger font issue is shown at the top of the attached image).
[results image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joqvG.jpg)

I am using Python 3.6.4,
Flask 1.0.2,
Browser: Goggle Chrome.

Comment: Check [Chrome's network panel](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/) to see if there's CSS served in one case and not in the other.

Comment: Same CSS is served both cases.